# Unix: Sort by uniq

Tags: sorting, unix, awk

I want this particular code to sort by most number of occurrences

```
cat /var/log/messages* |\
awk '{ print $2, $1, $5 }' | sort -k2,2M -k 1n |\
uniq -c | awk '{ print $2, $3, $1, $5, $4 }'
```

Right now it's sorted by date, I have tried and failed so many times to sort by most number of occurrences.

Current output:

```
27 Apr 1  rhsmd:
27 Apr 1  rsyslogd:
28 Apr 1  rhsmd:
29 Apr 1  rhsmd:
30 Apr 1  rhsmd:
10 May 1  rhsmd:
11 May 1  rhsmd:
11 May 1  rsyslogd:
12 May 1  rhsmd:
13 May 1  rhsmd:
14 May 1  rhsmd:
15 May 1  rhsmd:
16 May 1  rhsmd:
17 May 1  rhsmd:
18 May 1  rhsmd:
18 May 1  rsyslogd:
19 May 1  rhsmd:
1 May 1  rhsmd:
20 May 1  rhsmd:
21 May 1  rhsmd:
22 May 1  automount[1091]:
22 May 1  console-kit-daemon[1435]:
22 May 1  cpuspeed:
22 May 1  irqbalance:
22 May 1  rhnsd[1258]:
22 May 1  rhnsd[1259]:
22 May 1  rhsmd:
22 May 1  rpcbind:
22 May 1  rpc.statd[861]:
22 May 1  sm-notify[862]:
22 May 239  kernel:
22 May 2  mcelog:
```

I want `22 May 239  kernel:` to be at the top since it occurred 239 times.

I tried `sort -k3 -n` but It came out like this

```
22 May 2  abrtd:
22 May 1  automount[1091]:
22 May 7  cloud:
22 May 1  console-kit-daemon[1435]:
22 May 1  cpuspeed:
22 May 7  init:
22 May 1  irqbalance:
22 May 239  kernel:
```

Comment: ‍‍‍‍`most number of occurrences‍` of what?

Comment: Of entries. I'll edit to show an output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply change to:

```
 sort -k3 -rn -t' '
```

this will sort based on 3rd column of `awk` output. field seperator must be `' '` and order must be reverse.

Comment: I added `sort -k3 -n` at the end and its sorted from least to most, which is actually fine. Thanks!